# Sort customers by name according to country/language specific collation rules in a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sorting, grails, web, internationalization

We have customers from different countries using our Grails web application in their own native language (Swedish, Norwegian, Polish, German, Spanish etc) and they save data that is local to them. An example is a Customer-table having columns for first name and last name that need to be sorted as expected in the local language. This means that:

- A Swedish customer wants to sort the list of customer according to collation utf8mb4_swedish_ci which will sort a/o/å/ä/ö as expected. Örjan will be sorted last and not in the same place as Olof.
- A German customer wants to sort the list of customer according to collation utf8mb4_german2_ci which will sort ß/ss/u/ü as expected.
- Similar cases for other languages like Norwegian, Polish etc.

All our columns have the character set utf8mb4 to be able to support the storage of characters from multiple languages.

Previously we used utf8mb4_swedish_ci as our collation for all columns that we could sort on by but because we are getting customers from other countries and languages and moving to an international market we need to implement changes to support customers globally.

We are investigating the following solutions:

- Use utf8mb4_unicode_ci as collation in the database but add a collate expression like “order by firstname collate utf8mb4_swedish_ci” on all our queries depending on what language/location is used in the application.
- Use multiple columns in the database that has the target collation like “firstname_swedish”(utf8mb4_swedish_ci), “firstname_german” (utf8mb4_german2) or reference a specific table with different columns.
- Implement sorting in the application layer instead of the database.

Which solutions above would be the best approach regarding performance, implementation time and maintainability?

Comment: You want a complete list of customers from all countries, sorted somehow "correct"? It doesn't seem to be possible - think about chinese, right-to-left writings, etc. Probably you may group your list by customer country or language group.

Comment: Also you may apply collation to a query, not table: SELECT k FROM t1 ORDER BY k COLLATE latin1_german2_ci. But this wont allow you use indices. Thus, everything depends on the goal you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Each of our administration user (could be located in different countries like Sweden, Poland, Germany etc) need to only sort their own customers. But all customers are stored in the same Customer-table. 

Yes, the collation to a query is one of the solutions I presented above. As you say it would have a performance impact and we need to rewrite all our application logic. We are looking for a simpler solution that could be applied in the database only so we do not need to rewrite our data access code too much.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to summarize.

I would at once give up the idea to sort records on the application layer. All table data will have to be retrieved from database to application and this will quickly become a bottleneck and also this will require extra programming.

Apply collation to particular select query: minimum amount of programming, but MySQL will have to copy all records to temporary table, sort it with the given collation and then take your for example first 30 records. This will be done much more effectively than by your application, but as your table grows it will take more and more time and memory. However for, say, a few thousands of customers this is quite acceptable approach.

If you expect more customers and wish to optimize performance and server load, you can use additional columns, indexed with required collations: name_swe, name_ger, etc. Your application can store every customer's name to all of this columns and select only from the one wich has the required collation. This requires additional programming and redundant storage, but you will read only required data in required order, without temporary tables and additional processing.

Here are some thoughts on how to try to make this additional columns transparent to your application:

- you can fill columns with different collations automatically using MySQL generated columns or triggers - thus applications has to insert/update data only for the "name" column
- when performing select queries you can alias "name_swe", "name_ger" columns as "name" - thus application will have to read only single result column

Another version of this approach is to split customers table on several tables by customer country, each having required collation. You can union this tables to select all customers.

Also probably some DBMS can have multiple indices with different collations on the same column - this would solve the problem with minimum efforts, but as far as i can see mysql does not allow this.

I personally would start with setting collation for select query and take performance optimization measures when it will be needed.